# How to hide 'Configuration' tab for specific user

Tags: views

I'm looking for a way to configure the Backend for a specific user. 
For example: I want to hide the 'Configuration' tab.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily without any coding or other modules. Just go to */admin/people/permissions* and then uncheck the box titled "Use the administration pages and help" in the System section. The user's with that role will no longer see the configuration link.

[image]

Also note that you should make sure all your permissions are set accordingly. Just because you hide the link doesn't mean one who knows the right URLs can't still use the functionality.

Comment: Your way to handle it helps for a global config. Thank you!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it also disables the `Structure` and `Help` tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do a [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) and add an 'access callback'.

A good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157178/drupal-hook-menu-alter-add-access-callback-to-check-viewed-user-profile-is-n)

Comment: I'm really new in drupal. I'll study that. I'm sure drupal comes closer :) Thanks a lot.